# Reading Cookie that was saved using javascript into html

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I been trying to display Cookies that are saved using javascript into html page
I keep my Javascript in external file and I do not plan on putting this on a server this is for educational client purposes only

I store my cookies using this code **Javascript file**:`

```
function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
}

function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

function checkCookie() {
    var user=getCookie("username");
    var pass=getCookie("password");
    if (user != "" || pass != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user + " your password is: " + pass);
    } else {
       user = prompt("Welcome to my Site! Enter your name to begin! :","");
       pass = prompt("Make sure to include a password might be useful later! :","");
       if ((user != "" && user != null)&&(pass != "" && pass != null)) {
           setCookie("username", user, 30);
           setCookie("password", pass, 30);
       }               
    }   
}
```

`
**and HTML**:

```
<body onload="checkCookie()">
```

From what I gathered this seems to be working fine since the pop up dialogue says so however
what I want to do is to take this cookie that was saved with alert box and have it displayed on html side so it looks like this

```
<p>Your cookie is ("Displays the cookie here")</p>
```

What I tried to do so far is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
  document.write(getCookie("username"));
</script>
```

if someone could point me in right directions or say what I'm doing wrong I would be grateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the HTML element of `<div id='cookieInfo'></div>`

Change your Javascript to:

```
document.getElementById('cookieInfo').innerHTML = getCookie('userrname');
```

Answer (score 0):

try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maurosala/k3z899gd/1/)

this is javascript

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    checkCookie();
  document.getElementById("myc").innerHTML = getCookie("username");
})
```

this is your html

```
<p>Your name is <span id="myc"></span></p>
```